# extjs 6 override a mixin for RTL support in treeitem

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sass, extjs6-classic

I am trying to understand how to properly preform an override for a mixin on extjs 6.0.2.
[image]

this is the navigation panel on RTL, it is taken from the responsive admin dashboard example coming with extjs 6.

I need to flip the following class margin values to get it right on RTL:

```css
.x-treelist-navigation .x-treelist-item-text {
    color: #adb3b8;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 64px;
}
```

I have tried to create a theme and have also tried to override it on the application main scss file without success...

this is the ui that comes with the example:

```css
@include treelist-ui(
    $ui: 'navigation',
    $padding: 0 10px,

    // Black-ish background color
    $background-color: $panel-navigation-background-color,
    $toolstrip-background-color: #32404e,

    $tool-float-indicator-color: $panel-header-background-color,
    $tool-float-indicator-width: 5px,

    $tool-indicator-selected-color: $panel-header-background-color,
    $tool-indicator-selected-width: 5px,
    $tool-selected-background-color: mix(white, $panel-navigation-background-color, 10%),
    //$tool-selected-color: #fff,
    //$tool-selected-background-color: $panel-header-background-color,

    // Darker background for expanded subtrees
    $item-expanded-background-color: #2c3845,

    // Taller line height
    $item-line-height : $panel-navigation-item-line-height,

    $row-over-background-color: mix(white, $panel-navigation-background-color, 5%),
    $row-selected-background-color: mix(white, $panel-navigation-background-color, 10%),

    // Off-white text
    $item-icon-color: $panel-navigation-item-text-color,
    $item-expander-color: #fff,
    $item-text-color: #ADB3B8,

    // Brighter when hovered
    $item-icon-over-color: #fff,
    $item-expander-over-color: #fff,
    $item-text-over-color: mix(white, $panel-navigation-item-text-color, 50%),
    $item-text-font-size: 14px,

    // Various sizes for the pieces:
    $item-icon-font-size: 18px,
    $item-icon-width: 44px,
    $item-expander-font-size: 16px,
    $item-expander-width: 24px,

    // Style the "row indicator" (the vertical stripe on the left edge):
    $row-indicator-width: 5px,
    $row-indicator-selected-color: $panel-header-background-color,
    $row-indicator-selected-over-color: lighten($panel-header-background-color, 7%),
    $row-indicator-over-color: transparent
);
```

How can I get it done?